# force page or app.component reload angular

Tags: angular

I need to refresh some values in `app.component` in angular.
I have my navigation within `app.component.html` with `div *ngIf` and with a variable it decides which navigation is shown.

But at Login or Logout (when Navigation should change) it still shows the old value, because `app.component` doesn't refresh.

`app.component.html`:

```
<div *ngIf="session.xy == null or session.xy lt 1" class="navbar" role="banner">
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn">Navigation<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <nav>
        <a routerLink="/">Home</a>
        <a routerLink="/login">Login</a>
        <a routerLink="/register">Registrieren</a>
        <a routerLink="/Informationen">Informationen</a>
        <a routerLink="/#Kontakt">Kontakt</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="session.xy gt 0" class="navbar" role="banner">
  <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn">Navigation<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <nav>
        <a routerLink="/">Home</a>
        <a *ngFor="let item of session.items" routerLink="/item/{{item}}">Item: {{item}}</a>
        <a routerLink="/Pazzles">Item2</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`app.component.ts`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'xy-app';
  success: string = '';
  error: string = '';
  constructor(public sessionService: SessionService, public session: Session) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sessionService.ReadSession()
    .subscribe(
      (res: Session) => {
        this.session = res;
      },
      (err) => this.error = err
    );
  }
}
```

Login-Function:

```
Login(login: Login): Observable<Session> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/LogIn`, { data: login })
      .pipe(map((res) => {
        this.session = res;
        localStorage.setItem('session', res['sessid']);
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        return this.session;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
}
```

Logout-Function:

```
  DeleteSession(){
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/DeleteServerSess`, { data: this.sessid })
      .pipe(map((res) => {
        this.session = res;
        localStorage.clear;
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        return this.session;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
}
```

Comment: Show the actual code.

Comment: i have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved this "problem" with `location.replace("/");` with this it reloads the whole site after login and after logout.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh value with the update throw Input or Output

Or you can push force refresh with ApllicationRef

Just call include ApllicationRef dependence and call method tick

Comment: i have tried this one but the navigation does not reload in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want refresh app.component page if your session changes. Normally if you want angular detect changes automatically, you would pass session in as @Input. But since you are calling session from service. what you can do is when getting the new data, you manually let angular do the change for you. through injecting `changeDetectorRef`

```
constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

Then in your subscrible call

```
this._cdr.detectChanges();
```

Comment: thanks huantao, sounds for what i need - but after including this nothing changed for me ... still the problem with the navigation. Maybe i did something wrong? Here my `app.component.ts` now:
`export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
success: string = '';
error: string = '';
constructor(public sessionService: SessionService, public session: Session, private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {  }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.sessionService.ReadSession()
.subscribe(
  (res: Session) => {
    this._cdr.detectChanges();
    this.session = res;
  },
  (err) => this.error = err
);}}`

Comment: Call the detectChanges() function after you assign the new value

Comment: doesn't help too... the navigation does not change without a reload